# How to prevent tracked config files from being changed by merges in git?

Tags: git, repository, git-branch

I have a web project with two git branches (developing and production) and each one connects to a different server (dev and prod). Each branch has a set of tracked config files, such as different URLs, database options, sql exported files, etc. which are different on both branches.

Every time I try to merge those branches I get a lot of conflicts in these settings files which need to be resolved manually, but every now and then I miss something. In short, it is a nightmare. My question is therefore, how can I avoid this?

- Is there a way to prevent any changes to those config files while merging or rebasing?*

**Suggested Solution:**
*"Try to make those files untracked".* I tried this but whenever I pulled from the production file I get those files deleted and replaced, so I don't know if I should do it in a different way.

Comment: Add a local .gitignore file may be?

Comment: A probable answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to register a merge strategy as per-file attribute that will always use the current version. Here is how to do this (the idea is from [this blog](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/how-to-make-git-preserve-specific-files-while-merging-18c92343826b))

First you register a merge driver that

- does nothing and
- exits successfully.

The shell command `true` is exactly what we are looking for. The following line registers `true` as the *`alwaysours`* merge driver:

```
git config --local merge.alwaysours.driver true
```

Next, we need to tell git for which files to use this bogus merge driver. This is what the `.gitattributes` file is for. It supports the same small set of file patterns as the `.gitignore` file. For example

```
/configs/* merge=alwaysours
*.conf merge=alwaysours
```

would use our bogus merge driver for all files in '/config' or all files ending with '.conf'. It makes sense to also add this file to your git repository

```
git add .gitattributes
```

so that changes to it are tracked. There is one caveat though: *when you merge in a branch having the `.gitattributes` file, the `alwaysours` driver will also be used on this branch!* To avoid any problems arising from that, add the `alwaysours` merge driver for `.gitattributes` on *all* branches.

```
echo '/.gitattributes merge=alwaysours' > .gitattributes
git commit .gitattributes -m 'Register alwaysours driver for .gitattributes'
```

Of course this will break proper handling of any other settings you have in `.gitattributes`.

Comment: Hey just a question about this, after I do the commit. the files don't get overwritten which is good but is always asking me to push my changes which I don't want to do that because I don't want to push .gitattributes or the file that I don't want to get changed. How can I avoid this?

Comment: @SaulOrtega then you should not have committed your gitattributes file.

Comment: Didn't you say that I have to commit it? git commit .gitattributes -m 'Register alwaysours driver for .gitattributes'